# Alloy 1.8.3 transform issues after upgrade / possible new bug?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have found 2 issues that relate to the upgrade of Alloy to 1.8.3, 
I think both are a part of another bug thats been reported regarding transform and data binding, https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1477

I didn't want to just report it as a bug incase its down to something i'm doing??

1st one, I originally was referencing alloy_id in the transform for a list
but that started produced an error saying alloy_id could not be found, changing it to $model works but not sure if thats how we are supposed to do it now or its part of the above bug?

xml code (part)

```
<TableViewRow id="categoriesRow" UCATID="{UCATID}" 
            ParentID="{ParentID}" CategoryID="{CategoryID}" catName=    {catName}" 
            model="$model" hasDetail="{hasDetail}">
        <!-- TableViewRow id="categoriesRow" UCATID="{UCATID}" 
            ParentID="{ParentID}" CategoryID="{CategoryID}" catName="{catName}" 
            model="{alloy_id}" hasDetail="{hasChildren}"-->
            <Label id="rowTitle">{CategoryName}</Label>
        </TableViewRow>
```

The 2nd one is that setting the hasDetail to true or false (a boolean) for a table row to show there is more detail, this works on the iOS app by displaying the little icon fine in all versions so far,
however before the upgrade, validating the reference as a boolean worked, but now you have to reference it as a string
this can't be right??

controller.js code

```
function transformFunction(model) {
   var transform = model.toJSON();
   transform.catName = transform.CategoryName;
   transform.hasDetail = transform.hasChildren == "0" ? false : true;
   return transform;
}

$.winProdCats.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   Ti.API.info('e.row.hasDetail: ' + e.row.hasDetail );
   var iHaveBoolean = e.row.hasDetail;
   Ti.API.info('iHaveBoolean: ' + iHaveBoolean );
  //if(e.row.hasDetail){ //this don't work as a boolean anymore only as a string
    if(iHaveBoolean == "true"){
      parentID = e.row.CategoryID;
      getData();
      filterFunction(library);
      updateUI();
    } else {
      Ti.App.fireEvent('app:products:category:selected', {
          UCATID : e.row.UCATID,
          catName : e.row.catName,
          ParentID : e.row.ParentID,
          CategoryID : e.row.CategoryID
      });
      Alloy.Globals.navGroup.closeWindow($.winProdCats);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd love to get some more details on both of these issues. Please create a JIRA ticket or send me an email at fzandbergen at you know what.

Comment: Could you also try what Alloy 1.8.4 does for you?

Comment: thats interesting you say about the alloy version,  although the app build says it found the alloy version 1.8.4 it only shows 1.8.2, so i have no idea what is happening lol `[DEBUG] :  Looking for Titanium plugin id=ti.alloy version=1.8.4
[INFO] :   Found Titanium plugin id=ti.alloy version=1.8.4 
[INFO] :   Deploy type: development
[INFO] :   Building using iOS SDK: 9.3
[DEBUG] :  iOS WWDR certificate: installed
[INFO] :   Minimum iOS version: 7.1
[DEBUG] :  Alloy 1.8.2 by Appcelerator. The MVC app framework for Titanium.`

Comment: Do you use `ti build` or `appc run`? Those first two lines should have `1.0` as version, since that is the current version of the Alloy CLI plugin. Did you manually change that version in your `tiapp.xml`'s plugin section?

Comment: ok so running in the IDE alloy is still at version 1.8.2, running from OS X terminal i get version 1.8.5, used command line npm to remove and install alloy - its a start also found that there is a strange behaviour happening with the true false issue with hasDetail also that issue still exists, new issue is that if a row is set to false (this is all dynamically) and you click on that row it becomes a true and the hasDetail icon appears i've uploaded it to github https://github.com/Tempest99/alloy_fugitive_clone.git but seems that the alloy_id is ok in 1.8.5

Comment: also not sure if its related but in my iMac i keep getting a dialog error occurred box with the following in it, "An internal error occurred during: "Updating clients' server URLs".java.lang.NullPointerException" I don't get the issues with this on my macbook, but i do have the same alloy version issue & hasDetail on the macbook

Comment: The IDE (assuming Appcelerator Studio) uses the `appc` CLI, which embeds a version of Alloy depending on what you selected using `appc use`. You can find the embedded Alloy version with `appc alloy -v`. If you work in the terminal you can either use the `appc` CLI there as well, or use the global `ti` CLI which then will use the global `alloy` CLI. That might explain the two different versions you see.

Comment: yeah it seems that i have to set the sdk version using `appc use` in command line, and the studio just defaults to that version, no matter what is set in the `tiapp.xml` for that project, also if a newer sdk version is installed which i presume calls `use sdk-new-version` which looks like it will always default to the latest regardless of the `tiapp.xml` settings.  Is there a way to **force** use a specific `alloy version` from what i have seen it defaults to what is bundled in the SDK?? at the moment i have reverted back to SDK-5.2.0 which is using Alloy-1.7.33.

Comment: oh on a side note i fixed some errors i mentioned above, seemed to be a few permissions issues, i think thats an OS problem,  and i completely removed the studio and hidden npm, titanium etc folders and reinstalled from scratch

Comment: Actually `appc use` has nothing to do with the Titanium SDK. It can be confusing, which is why I recently did a [blog post](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/03/understanding-the-unified-appcelerator-cli/) on it. Officially there's no way to force a different Alloy version when you use the `appc` CLI, but there is a [workaround](https://gist.github.com/falkolab/da74a5fab2a7226090e357ab68426bf6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> an error saying alloy_id could not be found

This is [ALOY-1477](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1477), fixed in Alloy 1.8.4

> `//if(e.row.hasDetail){ //this don't work as a boolean anymore only as a string`

This is [ALOY-1480](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-1480), fix to be merged for Alloy 1.8.x next week, shipping with AppC CLI 5.3.0 end of April